# Fail to interpret PHP in Windows 7 Apache. Why?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7

I have follow every step of setting up apache & php in Windows 7.

I have the following set in the Httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"


<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
</IfModule>

PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
```

if it is .html, it displays no problem. (e.g. localhost/index.hmlt)
if it is .php, then it displays the source code (e.g. localhost/phpinfo.php   in which phpinfo.php is:

I run the phpinfo.php in command line and there is no problem. it is the apache server that doesn't recognized PHP.  so what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encasing the type code in the wrong module

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .php
</IfModule>
```

should be

```
<IfModule php5_module.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

most distributions will include a php config file that does this for you in the correct way

DC